Using the Google Map API to get GeoJSON map data
I want to request GeoJson data( not my own data, but all map data like OSM ) from the Google Map API to then use in Babylon.js to create a 3D model.  Is this possible?  I see there is a lot of referencing of GeoJson and that there is a solution using THREE.js.  I just want to grab the data and parse it in a custom application, and thinking Google data would be better than OSM and MapBox.
Have not tried anything as of yet as I do not yet have an account to do so.
